# Swift's [weak self] alternative for C++

Tags: c++, lambda, lifetime

In Swift programming language it is common to pass `self` by weak reference into the closure, e.g:

```
self.someAsyncFunction(param1, param2, { [weak self] in
    self?.doSomething()
})
```

Very handy thing to my mind.

Is there any similar in C++? For instance:

```
this->someAsyncFunction(param1, param2, [this](){
    this->doSomething();
});
```

Instance of caller (or `this`) may have been deleted at the moment when lambda is executed. As a result, it crashes on `this->doSomething()`.
In other words, I want to have something like this:

```
this->someAsyncFunction(param1, param2, [weak this](){
    if (this)
        this->doSomething();
});
```

which is not valid C++ code of course.

Is there any good practice on handling such issue?

Ideally, solution must handle all possible sutuations such as

- `this` is created by `new` and deleted with `delete`.
- `this`'s lifetime is controlled by `std::shared_ptr`.
- `this`'s lifetime is controlled by `boost::intrusive_ptr`.

Comment: There is https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/weak_from_this but it requires a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: C++ is not a managed language, so `this` will always be `this`, and it will never suddenly change, unexpectedly, and become anything but `this`. `this` is forever. If something else deletes `this`, then your `this` will still be the same `this`, but using `this` becomes undefined behavior. `this` is not fair, but `this` is C++. Therefore, the only options to explore here will involve, by necessity, smart pointers.

Comment: C++ tends to favor "you don't pay for it unless you opt-in for the facility (and overhead)".  The `std::shared_ptr` and `std::enable_shared_from_this` (linked by Sombrero Chicken) is the facility (and overhead) you are looking for.  From an architectural standpoint, I do not like my objects to be self-aware they are owned by a `shared_ptr`.  But if I really need them to be, I'd use it.

Comment: Can you alter the **class** (however its instances are managed) to support this usage?